# How to control the size of each controls in winform

Tags: c#, winforms

Now I'm making a simple GUI showing 2-D chart.

In the code, `panel2.Width` becomes `1360` after running

```
panel2.Width = (RawViewVisible.Width + 1) * data_width;
```

and `form_width` becomes `1485` after running

```
form_width = X_OFFSET + (GAP + SELF_CONTROL_SIZE) * 2 + panel2.Width;
```

But `panel2.Width` changes to `4285` abruptly after running `this.Width = form_width;`

Very curious thing is `this.Width` is not `1485` but `3860`.

I don't understand why it happens and how to solve it.

```
const int GAP = 1;
const int X_OFFSET = 3;
const int SELF_CONTROL_SIZE = 60;
const int STATUS_STRIP_SIZE = 22;
int form_width, form_height;

panel2.Width = (RawViewVisible.Width + 1) * data_width;
panel2.Height = (RawViewVisible.Height + 1) * data_height;

form_width = X_OFFSET + (GAP + SELF_CONTROL_SIZE) * 2 + panel2.Width;
form_height = panel1.Height + 3 + panel2.Height + (GAP + SELF_CONTROL_SIZE) * 2 + 1 + STATUS_STRIP_SIZE;

this.Width = form_width;
this.Height = form_height;
this.MinimumSize = new System.Drawing.Size(form_width, form_height + 300);
```

Comment: Pro Tip: Use the Anchor and Docking tooling provided. Even if you get this perfect on your monitor chances are it wont look the same on my "15 or "42. Anchor, Docking and FlowPanels will preserve the overall layout and you've got better things to code than pixel alignment!  Oh and a stab at your question - if you use GroupBox controls instead of Panel control you should get the desired behaviour, Panels are a bit weird.

Comment: Thank you, after replacing to GroupBox the weird symptom disappered.

Comment: [Position and layout of controls (Windows Forms .NET)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/winforms/controls/layout?view=netdesktop-6.0&WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235)

Comment: I found out what impact to this symptom. When I set  both Anchor Left and Right for panel, picture or any box controls then the weird symptom happens. Setting both Anchor Top and Bottom doesn't make any problem. I don't understand why I just solved it by setting Anchor Top and Left.